# MongoTemplate Limit query issue

Tags: count, find, limit

I am using MongoTemplate to execute my Mongo queries.
I wanted to know if count works with limit set?

Also why find query searches full collection (according to query) although limit is set?
For e.g. the query i wrote might result in having 10000 records, but i want only 100 records and for that i have set limit to 100 and then fired find query. But still query goes on to search full 10000 records.

```
dataQuery.limit(100);
List<logs> logResultsTemp = mongoTemplate1.find(dataQuery, logs.class);
```

Is their any limitations in using limit command?

Answer (score 4):

Limit works fine (at least on spring data version 1.2.1 that I use). Perhaps it was a problem on your your version?

About count, there is a specific method to get your collection count, so you don't need to care about the amount of data that your system will fetch:

```
mongoTemplate.count(new Query(), MyCollection.class)
```

Btw, if you try this directly on your mongodb console: db.myCollection.limit(1).count() you will get the actual total of documents in your collection, not only one. An so it is for the mongoTemplate.count  method, so:

```
mongoTemplate.count(new Query().limit(1), MyCollection.class)
```

will work the same way.